# Ajax loading Mvc Content Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I know, there are several questions with near the same problem. But i cant figure it out, where my mistake is.

So at first my situation:
I'll load my content with ajax and push it to the site.

```
$.ajax({
url: _this.url,
contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",
type: "GET",
dataType: "html",
data: {
    stamp: Date.now()
},
success: function (result) {
    _this.app = $("<div id='" + _this.frameId + "' />")
        .addClass("place-top-left page")
        .css({
            "height": "100%",
            "z-index": 4000
        })
        .append($(result))
        .appendTo(document.body);
    if (loadedCallback) {
        loadedCallback();
    }
},
error: function (xhr, status) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
}
});
```

My controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
var howToContent = Manager.Get(id);

var howToModel = new HowToModel()
{
    MediaID = howToContent.Media.ID,
    HowToTitle = howToContent.Title,
    Name = howToContent.Name,
    BusinessIds = howToContent.BusinessIDs.Select(it => it.ToString()).ToArray()
};

return View(howToModel);
}
```

And my View:

```
@model Hsetu.Help.Web.Areas.System.Models.HowTo.HowToModel           
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Leitfaden bearbeiten";
   Layout = "~/Areas/System/Views/Shared/AppSite.cshtml";
}

@section ScriptCSS{
  @Scripts.Render("~/uploadScripts")
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <fieldset>
       <label>
          @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Name)
       </label>
       <label>
          @Html.EditorFor(m => m.HowToTitle)
       </label>
       <label>
          @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BusinessIds)
       </label>
   </fieldset>
}
```

The Error ill get is: 
**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type Hsetu.Help.Web.Areas.System.Models.HowTo.HowToModel, but this dictionary requires a model item of type System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString**

So it will step through the Controller and the View if i debug the code. I'll also get the right model and values!

Only the result on the success function from ajax is a json return with this error message.

This works for same code but without passing this howToModel into the view.

---

On the other side i found out, if ill use ajaxcall like this it will also work?! Sorry.. but WTF is the diffrence between this ajaxcalls?????

```
$.ajax({
    url: _this.url,
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {                        
        stamp: Date.now()
    }
})
.success(function (result) {
    _this.app = $("<div id='" + _this.frameId + "' />")
    .addClass("place-top-left page")
    .css({
        "height": "100%",
        "z-index": 4000
    })
    .append($(result))
    .appendTo(document.body);
if (loadedCallback) {
    loadedCallback();
}
})
.error(function (xhr, status) {
    alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

---

So my question is, how can i get the first ajaxcall working? I need it with this syntax.. so there is no way around. And maybe someone can explain me the difference between the ajax. Doesnt find a really necessary reason!
Thanks

Comment: putting a view in a view is a bad idea.  you need to change your controller to return partial view.  You aren't specifying a partial name though.  What are you trying to return with this call?

Comment: im trying to get the html content of the view.
I've also tried to return a PartialView() Content() and also MvcHtmlString always same error!

Comment: ajax call are designed to update fields or check information.  Or update partials.  They aren't designed for entire view replacement.  returning a view will include your layout page, references and a lot of other stuff you don't need duplicated

Comment: if you see it in this case its something like a update of a partial view! i dont render a whole page with html/body tags! its only a div with a form.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the ajax calls is that the .error() call *on* the returned object of the .ajax() call returns a [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), which is chainable, and allows multiple handlers to be set, whereas passing *in* an `error:` function can only be done once per `ajax()` call -- I believe that is an older syntax.

(BTW `.error()` is deprecated, and you should use .fail() instead -- if you were using that approach)

Regarding your MVC (server-side) error: this is often the kind of error message I get when I attempt to pass in an property value that is null into a strongly-typed helper. Check the values of `.Name`, `.HowToTitle`, and `.BusinessIds` for nulls.

Comment: i've checked all properties.. nothing is null! Like i write in my question, the values and all seems to be fine to me!